# "MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token" when inner tag with the same name as outer

Tags: java, xml, jackson

When trying to deserialize XML

```
<Schedule>
    <Dates>
        <Calendar>USD</Calendar>
        <Convention>ModifiedFollowing</Convention>
        <Tenor>1M</Tenor>
        <Dates>
            <Date>2012-01-06</Date>
            <Date>2012-04-10</Date>
            <Date>2012-07-06</Date>
            <Date>2012-10-08</Date>
            <Date>2013-01-07</Date>
            <Date>2013-04-08</Date>
        </Dates>
    </Dates>
</Schedule>
```

into

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ScheduleDto {

    @JsonProperty(value = "Dates")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<DatesDto> dates = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Dates")
public class DatesDto {

    @JsonProperty(value = "Calendar")
    private String calendar;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Convention")
    private String convention;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Tenor")
    private String tenor;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Date")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Dates")
    private List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

it throws an error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 108] (through reference chain: sh.zandr.sandbox.how2jackson.domain.ScheduleDto["Dates"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->sh.zandr.sandbox.how2jackson.domain.DatesDto["Dates"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

But if I change xml to

```
<Schedule>
    <DatesObj>
        <Calendar>USD</Calendar>
        <Convention>ModifiedFollowing</Convention>
        <Tenor>1M</Tenor>
        <Dates>
            <Date>2012-01-06</Date>
            <Date>2012-04-10</Date>
            <Date>2012-07-06</Date>
            <Date>2012-10-08</Date>
            <Date>2013-01-07</Date>
            <Date>2013-04-08</Date>
        </Dates>
    </DatesObj>
</Schedule>
```

and ScheduleDto to

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ScheduleDto {

    @JsonProperty(value = "DatesObj")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<DatesDto> dates = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

it works correctly.

Is it a jackson bug? Because I'm expecting that it would be processed recursively, so during deserialization of inner `<Dates>` it wouldn't know anything about outer `<Dates>`.
Or it can be somehow configured to correctly deserialize original XML (because I can't change input)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug. This may be the issue (or one of the duplicates of this issue): https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/294

It may be fixed in the version 2.11.1. That's all I found.